# stop testing from running mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

So I have some code in a `before()` that is executed before any tests.  Is there some way in the function to be able to stop mocha from running any tests?

```
before(function() {
  if(someCondition === true) {
    //kill mocha before it executes any tests
  }
});
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the the `done` callback with an error:

```
before(function(done) {
  if(someCondition === true) {
    return done('Error');
  }
});
```